# JS: getElementsByTagName get all * but one element

Tags: javascript

I'm using a script where I want to select all the nodes of a web page

```
    nodes = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

but I want to exclude one element, say #ThisID, and **all of its children**

how do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll),

```
nodes = document.body.querySelectorAll('*:not(#ThisID)');
```

- `*` will select all the elements from the body.
- `:not(selector)` will filter out the elements related to the supplied selector.

For excluding the child nodes of the node that needs to be filtered,

```
var nodes = Array.from(document.body.querySelectorAll('*:not(#ThisID)'));
var filter = document.querySelector("#ThisID");

nodes = nodes.filter(function(node) {
    return !filter.contains(node);
});

console.log(nodes); // This will not contain the node #test1 as well its children.
```

Iterate over the collected nodes and filter out the required nodes by using [`.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dnhehvwf/1/)

Comment: this solution excludes only that element... not its children?!

Comment: I wonder if maybe should i simply remove them in the array generated...maybe easier?

Comment: @Francesco Yeah. I am working on a solution for that. I didn't realize that part.